# The beta theme has extra space in between multi-line titles

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, design, beta-phase

When clicking on a title that has broken down to a new line, there's a 3-pixel space in between the first line and the second line. This is only occurring on the new beta theme for me. I tried it on Stack Overflow and several other full-theme sites and this issue doesn't seem to exist.

[image: Unclickable area]

The problem I'm having is sometimes I go through a list and open the questions in a new tab by right clicking on the link and selecting Open in new tab in the menu. For me, it's always the first option, so I don't ever really look at the menu before clicking. However, if the mouse happens to be in that 3-pixel line of space in between, then the menu changes since it's not over a link and the first option is now Back. It may be minor, but this has happened enough times to me that it's become irritating and I'm complaining about it, so can it please be fixed?

P.S. Tested in Chrome 20 and Firefox 14.

**Update:** Out of boredom, I was testing on more sites. This also occurs on [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com), [Judaism](http://judaism.stackexchange.com), and [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). All of those are newer ones near the end of the list in the footer, so perhaps a style changed somewhere that's getting applied to newer themes?

Comment: This can be fixed by applying `display: block` to the link and removing the `margin-bottom`.